# My Java Actionlistener won't change a JTextArea when a JButton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextarea

This is my-almost completed Choose Your Own Adventure Game. The Actionlistener is broken. It works for the 'teh internets' part, but the rest of the Actionlistener won't make the buttons change the text.

Rest of Actionlistener is very similar to first part.

Please Help.

EDIT: Took out irrelevant parts

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TheGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

/**
 * @param args
 */

String gameText = "You wake up in the morning feeling like a sir. As is tradition, you need electronics of any kind to keep your mind running (going outside is out of the question. Nothing exciting in the real world). There are many options available to you, but the internet and games are the ones that appeal the most. Do you want to surf the web or use an app?";
private final JTextArea adventureArea;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 JButton option1;
 JButton option2;

    public TheGame(){

        option1 = new JButton("Click here for teh interwebs");
         option1.addActionListener(this);
        option1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
         option1.setVisible(true);

        option2 = new JButton("Click here for teh entertainments");
        option2.addActionListener(this);
         option2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
         option2.setVisible(true);


        this.adventureArea = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        adventureArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        adventureArea.setLineWrap(true);
        adventureArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        adventureArea.setEditable(true);
        adventureArea.setText(gameText);





    }
```

Actionlistener:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==option1){//internets

            String gameText="";
            adventureArea.setText(gameText);
            option1.setText("Dark!");
            option2.setText("Light!");
            if(e.getSource()==option1){//Dark

                //String gameText="";
                //adventureArea.setText(gameText);

            }if (e.getSource()==option2){//Light
                //gameText="");
                option1.setText("Ponies!");
                option2.setText("Videos!");
                if(e.getSource()==option1){//Ponies

                    gameText="";
                    adventureArea.setText(gameText);
                    option1.setText("Read!");
                    option2.setText("Socialize!");
                    if(e.getSource()==option1){//Read
                        gameText="";
                        adventureArea.setText(gameText);
                        option1.setText("Leave!");
                        option2.setText("Leave!");

                        if(e.getSource()==option1){//leave

                            System.exit(0);
                        }else if (e.getSource()==option2){//leave

                            System.exit(0);
                        };
                    }else if (e.getSource()==option2){//socialize
                        gameText="";
                                adventureArea.setText(gameText);
                                option1.setText("Leave!");
                                option2.setText("Leave!");
                        if(e.getSource()==option1){//leave

                            System.exit(0);
                        }else if (e.getSource()==option2){//leave

                            System.exit(0);
                        };

                    };
```

Comment: OMG I love to read a bad description of a problem, and to scroll to see the problematic part in a huge snippet of code. Thank you.

Comment: That's a huge snippet of code *without*  line numbers :-(

Comment: Good presentation like this example, really helps. LOL

Comment: Sometimes, I like to lean back and imagine the conversations that these "developers" have with their classmates / co-workers.

Comment: Ugh. Use anonymous or inner classes instead for each button's action listener of a billion if-else-ifs. That would simplify it both for you and others reading your code.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin I culled it. Will you look now?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is :

You have two main check :

```
if (e.getSource() == option1) {//internets
...
}
```

and

```
 else if (e.getSource() == option2) {//Entertainments
           ...      
      }
```

you believe that if the user click on the first button , and change the information on it , then you make a click again on the same button it will run the code inside the first `if` condition

when you click on the button , you make an action , first thing make is to check which button you click , s even if you change the text on the button , this button is same one ,

explain :
if you click on `option1 = new JButton("Click here for teh interwebs");` then the first if condition will match , so it will change the text on this button to become `option1.setText("Dark!");` , then you click on "Dark" (option2) then you will go to the action again which will check on the button (option2) so the second if condition will be match

---

instead of nested `if` condition , change the condition to be check with the text of button , Like that :
 `if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Dark!"))`

---

for Example : for the change in `Click here for teh interwebs`

```
   if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Click here for teh interwebs")) {//internets
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Dark!")) {//Dark         
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Light!")) {//Light
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Ponies!")) {//Ponies
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Read!")) {//Read
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Socialize!")) {//socialize
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Videos!")) {//Videos
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Youtube!")) {//Youtbe
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("Dubstep videos!")) {//Dubstep
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Gaming videos!")) {//Gaming
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Netflix!")) {//Netflix
   } else if (e.getSource() == option1 && option1.getText().equals("MLP:FIM!")) {//MLP
   } else if (e.getSource() == option2 && option2.getText().equals("Whatever the third recommendation on your ‘Suggested’ list is!!")) {//Random
   }
```

Comment: Your first few paragraphs I didn't understand. COuld you explain that?

Comment: i mean if you change the text on option2 button it will still option2 button so when you click on it again after you change the text on it , you will go to the one of the main if condition you have , i don't know how to explain it , but the actionlistner run once you click on the button , and even if you change the text and reclick on the button again , it will call the action method from the start